# Binary operation on continuously differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

This question deals with sets of functions.

The notation $C^0$ means continuous and $C^1$ means differentiable functions with continuous first derivative. The domain is also indicated. Thus $C^1[0, 1]$ is the set of differentiable functions with continuous first derivatives, and domain $[0, 1]$.

Define $∗$ on $C^1[0, 1$] by:

$$(f ∗ g)(x) = \int_0^x (f'(t)g'(t))dt + f(0) + g(0)$$

Is $∗$ a binary relation? Is it commutative? Associative? Prove your assertions.
(You will need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Where have you gotten stuck?

Answer (score 0):

$\ast$ is a binary operation because(F. Theorem of Calculus) $\dfrac {d}{dx}(f*g)=f' (x)g' (x)\in C^0.$ The operation is commutative because $f' (x) g '(x)=g '(x) f' (x) $and$ f (0)+g (0)=g (0)+f (0)$, but it isn't associative. For example take $f (x)=x, h (x)=g (x)=1$.